# Another effect to slide views on fame.us app?

Tags: famo.us

i have 2 views in fame.us app, and slide in EdgeSwapper view, and i want change default effect of EdgeSwapper.show().
I want effect like a smooth transition forward and backwards, how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Famo.us is open source, so you could make a copy (clone) of the **[`EdgeSwapper`](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/develop/src/views/EdgeSwapper.js)** view.

Change the `_transformMap` function in your new view to a new transform.

**[Here is a jsBin](http://jsbin.com/notika/1/edit?js,output)** of a new view called `BackSwapper` that has a new transform as follows:

```js
function _transformMap(zMax, progress) {
    //return Transform.translate(this._size[0] * (1 - progress), 0, zMax * (1 - progress));
  return Transform.translate(0, 0, -this._size[0] * (1 - progress));
}
```